# Why Positive and Negative Look Ahead Regex is not supported in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query in oracle like

```
select regexp_substr('a,b','[A-Za-z]+(?=,)',1,level) 
from dual 
connect by level<3;
```

expected output

```
 a
 b
```

but it is returning nothing.

So it may be possible that positive and negative lookahead is not supported by oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression to get the desired result

```
select regexp_substr('a,b','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual 
connect by regexp_substr('a,b', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jasti but i want to know that whether positive and negative lookahead are supported in oracle or not.